# centos cron logs are not executed

Tags: centos, logging, cron

I have been trying to setup a cronjob on CentOS but it doesn't seem to work. I have been deleting the cron's logfile to see all newly created logs and I have been restarting  crond but `/var/log/conf` wasn't getting recreated?

`logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf` is showing me an error

```
error: stat of /var/log/cron failed: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`No such file or directory` can imply a number of things.  The two most common cryptic cases are:

- You tried to traverse a broken symlink
- You tried to open a file in a nonexistent directory

Check whether these are the case.  It can also happen if your program expects the file to exist when opened and hasn't specified to the operating system that it's OK to create it if it doesn't.  You could try something like `touch /var/log/cron` so it has something to stat; this command will create an empty file there.

Comment: This may be a result of the syslog daemon not running. It's possible that the log files were not being created due to the daemon being in a stopped state. After (re)starting the service you may find the file is created for you.

Answer (score 0):

So you still have problems with the cronjob?

Its not great practise to delete log files, if you really want to empty a system log file, better to redirect nothing to it like this:

`> /var/log/cron`

Comment: I have been recreating as @Falcon Momot advised touch /var/log/cron and seems to work now. I'm going to retest my cronjob now